# how to re-plot one curve for a multiply curves figure on matplotlib of python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am doing a Tkinter project, I need to plot a real-time dataset from a sensor, and also a theoretical curve in the same plot. I need to use an user entry value to adjust the theoretical curve to compare with the real-time plot in real-time. The problem is I do not want to reset all graph, how could I replot the threoretical curve then? I could not use plt.cla(), both curves use the same ax. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to modify a line after plotting it. You find plenty of examples when you search for matplotlib and animation (e.g. [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/basic_example.html)).

You probably could do something like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
lines = plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,4]) # plot your 'theoretical curve'

# lines is a list containing line objects, in this case, of length 1.
line = lines[0] 
line.set_data([1,2,3],[4,2,3]) #  update the 'theoretical curve'
```